# Was the tenth of an ephah in Exodus 29:40 considered a tithe as stated in Malachi 3:10?

Tags: exodus, malachi, tithes

> Exodus 29:40
>
> With the first lamb offer **a tenth of an ephah of** the finest flour mixed with a quarter of a hin of oil from pressed olives, and a quarter of a hin of wine as a drink offering.

> Malachi 3:10
>
> Bring **the whole tithe** into the storehouse, that there may be food in my house. Test me in this,’ says the Lord Almighty, ‘and see if I will not throw open the floodgates of heaven and pour out so much blessing that there will not be room enough to store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the regulations in Exodus 29 are not dealing with tithing, and so are not related to the prophecy given about tithing in Malachi 3:10:

> "Bring the whole tithe into the storehouse, that there may be food in my house."

---

#### Exodus 29:

> 35 “Thus you shall **do to Aaron and to his sons**, according to all that I have commanded you. Through seven days shall you ordain them,
> 36 and every day you shall offer a bull as a sin offering for
> atonement. Also you shall purify the altar, when you make atonement
> for it, and shall anoint it to consecrate it. 37 Seven days you shall
> make atonement for the altar and consecrate it, and the altar shall be
> most holy. Whatever touches the altar shall become holy.
>
> 38 “**Now this is what you shall offer** on the altar: two lambs a year
> old day by day regularly. 39 One lamb you shall offer in the morning,
> and the other lamb you shall offer at twilight. 40 And with the first
> lamb a tenth measure of fine flour mingled with a fourth of a
> hin of beaten oil, and a fourth of a hin of wine for a drink
> offering.

This chapter of Exodus is dealing with the **consecration of priests, not tithing**. The end of Deuteronomy 14 / Leviticus 27 provide more information on how the main portion of tithing was to be done under the covenant of Moses, and these would be the sorts of things referenced by Malachi:

- [Deuteronomy 14:22-29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2014:22-29)
- [Leviticus 27:30-34](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus+27%3A30-34)
- [The Mosaic Law on Tithing](http://www.askelm.com/tithing/thi006.htm)
- [Jewish Law StackExchange: "What portion of his income would a Jew following the sacrificial laws
  give?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9690/what-portion-of-his-income-would-a-jew-following-the-sacrificial-laws-give)